# Does Aumann's agreement theorem extend to moral propositions?

Tags: ethics, probability, rationality, bayesian

[Aumann's agreement theorem](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Aumann%27s_agreement_theorem) says:

> two perfectly rational agents with the same prior estimate of an event's probability and common knowledge of one another's posterior estimates cannot come to different posteriors.

Suppose we treat a statement like "murder is wrong" as a proposition to evaluate in a Bayesian way. For instance, we might evaluate conditionals like P(murder is wrong | people say murder is wrong), or P(murder is wrong | people don't want to be murdered). Does Aumann's agreement theorem thus imply that two Bayesian rationalists with common priors, with common knowledge of each other's posterior probabilities, must agree on the same set of moral propositions?

Or is there something fundamentally improper about treating a statement like "murder is wrong" in a Bayesian way? If so, where or why does the Bayesian approach break down?

See also [this paper](http://mason.gmu.edu/%7Erhanson/prior.pdf) which proposes to weaken the common-prior requirement, by instead having the two agents agree about the origins of their priors.

Comment: Some, I think, would argue that claimed events don't necessarily either happen or don't.  For example, if someone claims that murder happened, but what happened was instead just a form illegal homicide or manslaughter, is the person who used the term 'murder' informally, incorrect?  And not all murders are the same legally, where murder of the 1st degree isn't the same as murder of the 2nd degree.  So, I would think skepticism warranted that precise probabilities can get applied to all cases, and that would rule out Aumann's theorem as always applicable.

Comment: It breaks down from the beginning, "probability that murder is wrong" makes no sense if one is a moral realist (because morality is non-contingent) and makes no sense if one is not (because moral sentences are non-propositional). [Moral rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rationalism) is a dubious idea since Hume because ises and oughts have different origins.

Comment: @Conifold If one is a moral realist, or any other kind of realist, one can still assign Bayesian probabilities to non-contingent propositions. These are subjective probabilities, describing the individual's lack of knowledge. The probabilities are not inherent in the phenomenon being described. Additionally, if one is not a moral realist, one can still assign a non-zero Bayesian probability to moral realism; Bayesians generally assign non-zero probabilities to any proposition, virtually never exactly 0.

Comment: @causative If I understand this right then it will be one's epistemic prior that murder is wrong without any sort of testing available to update it. And even epistemic probabilities are not assigned to non-propositions, like imperatives of deontologists or emotional attitudes of moral sentimentalists. It is similar to aesthetic sentences like "Mona Lisa is beautiful" that anti-realists treat as non-propositional. One can update their attitudes but it is hard to see how that translates into updating probabilities.

Comment: @Conifold I gave an example of how the prior for "murder is wrong" could be updated by the observation that others think murder is wrong. Normally, P(X | others think X) > P(X), so this counts as a Bayesian update. About your other point, yes, this only really applies to some form of moral realism. But like I said before, if one is not a moral realist, one generally still assigns a nonzero probability to moral realism being correct, from which it would follow that P(murder is wrong) is also nonzero.

Comment: I suspect that what people say or want are not good grounds for updating probability for a rationalist (compare to updating "evolution theory is right" based on *that*). But if that counts one can also update X's probabilities of Y's moral or aesthetic sentiments (Y can be a community) based on what people say about Y or what Y say they want. I just feel that this is not so much probability of A as probability that A is held by someone(s).

Comment: @Conifold Well, what other people say about a proposition is not terribly strong evidence (unless they are relevant domain experts, when the person performing the Bayesian update is not a domain expert himself), but it is evidence, and a rationalist would take it into account among other factors. Yes, a rationalist would say the probability of the theory of evolution being correct is slightly influenced by the number of people (especially the number of domain experts) who accept/reject it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130506/discussion-between-conifold-and-causative).